# Analytical solution to fitting two functions

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, estimation

I have two oscillatory functions $f(x)$ and $(k x)^2 g(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ are known and it is also known that the two functions are approximately similar. How can I analytically find the best estimate of $k$, $\hat{k}$ in the least square (or any norm $p$) sense? I can do it numerically by discretizing it and running it through any of the several solvers/algorithms, but is it possible to do this analytically?

Comment: The question as it is posed has no answer. You have two functions that are similar (no exact definition of that?) so what principle would determine $k$? Basically, there is no connection in your question that would tell us ANYTHING about $k$, so no, you cannot calculate $k$ yet.

Comment: @5xum I could, for instance, discretize the support of the two functions (known) as a vector $\mathbf{x}$ and do $\hat{k}=\text{argmin}_k \Vert f(\mathbf{x}) - k^2 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{I}\mathbf{x}\ g(\mathbf{x})\Vert_2$. I'm not sure why you need a precise definition of "similar" when I've stated that I'd like to find the best estimate in a least square sense. They need not even be similar and you can still find a $k$ that satisfies this.

Comment: You don't understand my comment. See, the thing is you did not provide a clear description of what you want to do. In fact, you have not provided ANY description of what your goal is. Do you want to find the minimum $k$ so that the norm of $f(x) - (kx)^2g(x)$ is smaller than $1$?

Comment: @5xum Sorry, I figured the "least square" sense was self explanatory (I'm probably not familiar with your terminology). I want to find the $k$ such that the norm of $f(x)-k^2 x^2 g(x)$ is minimum.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution I adopted for similar problems in order to avoid discretization and curve fit $$k^2=\frac{\int_a^b x^2 g(x) \, dx}{\int_a^b f(x) \, dx}$$ I even wonder if this does not correspond exactly to the least square fit solution for an infinite number of data points for $a<x<b$.

Comment: That might work, thanks, I'll try it out. Do you know if there's a way to extend it if $k$ was not separable — i.e., the second function is $h(k x)g(x)$ where $h$ is known, but cannot be separated into a product of two functions?

Comment: @jkk. This works (I use it for decades !). Are you meaning that $h$ is a known function of $kx$ and that you need to get $k$ ? Give me an example to work.

Comment: How about $h(z)=\exp(-z)$? Then $h(kx)=\exp(-k^2 x^2)$ which doesn't separate out quite as nicely as $k^2 x^2$.

Comment: Please give me $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. It could work if we can analytically integrate $h(kx)g(x)$.